# Read two visa instruments in parallel with Matlab

Tags: matlab, visa, spmd

I try to read data from two Keysight oscilloscopes in parallel with Matlab (2015a). To do that I use the parallel computing toolbox with the spmd command. I have a function to read the data which accepts a visa object as parameter and returns the rawdata. This works fine outside the spmd command like this (scope1 and scope2 are open visa objects):

```
scope = {scope1, scope2}
scopedata1 = scopeGetCh1Raw(scope{1});
scopedata2 = scopeGetCh1Raw(scope{2});
```

I get the data from both oscilloscopes.

If I do:

```
spmd
    scopedata = scopeGetCh1Raw(scope{labindex});
end
```

I get the following error:

```
Error detected on workers 1 2.

Caused by:
    Error using icinterface/fprintf (line 147)
    OBJ must be connected to the hardware with FOPEN.
    Error using icinterface/fprintf (line 147)
    OBJ must be connected to the hardware with FOPEN.
```

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Cheers 
Nils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workers operating on the body of your `spmd` block are separate *processes*. I presume you'll need to call `fopen` inside `spmd`, something like:

```
spmd
    myScope = fopen(...); % do whatever to open the scope
    scopedata = scopeGetCh1Raw(myScope);
end
```